# Issues with Foreign Data Wrapper for RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: amazon-rds

I have been trying to create a foreign data wrapper and import schema from one **RDS database** instance with public accessibility set to yes onto another RDS database instance. 
Able to create the server and user mapping, however when I try importing the schema it times out with the below error:

> SQL Error [08001]: ERROR: could not connect to server "server_name"

For RDS instance with public accessibility set to "yes", we only find a public IP and import schema from some other instance times out.

The same procedure works fine if the target instance from where schema is being imported has its public accessibility set to "no"

Can you please advise.